macOS showing app alert-dialogues in other screens instead of contained-in apps
I work on 3 displays, while I run my application on left most display, the alert appears on right most display. And, I don't think this is a great design of macOS. I understand the dialogs appear on primary or focussed monitor.
How do I make macOS application alert-dialogs appear in the app itself. Is there any NSUserDefaults command that I can run or is it the way macOS behave?
I work on 3 display and my setup is like this.


Is the right-most Display the primary display? If you change how your screens are arranged, and connect them using different connectors, which display do the alerts show on? I would guess because the alerts are an OS hook, that they are not necessarily associated with a running application window in order to be placed on the same screen, but that is only a guess.

In System Settings > Displays > Arrange…, drag the little menu bar image to the image of the display where you want to have dialogs like this get shown.
macOS's windowing model has no concept of an app having a primary window or a primary display, so there is no concept of "in the app" for dialogs to get displayed in. Apps can have a bunch of equally important windows in each display. Given that, the best macOS can do is always display dialogs in your primary display, which is set by dragging the little menu bar in the "Arrange" window as described above.
If a dialog only applies to a certain window, the app developer is supposed to use APIs that make it modal to that window (used to be a "sheet" that came out form the window's title bar, but now just grays out the window and displays in the middle of the window). But if a dialog isn't specific to a window, it gets shown on the primary display.

I totally understand this. Even if I make the center screen as primary and if I have application running on left most display, the alert would appear on center display. I want the alert to appear on the app-display itself.
Also the sheet patter is long gone I guess. I saw that sheet pattern last time on Mac OS X Lion.

@KevvKeka Oops yes, sheets aren't sheets anymore. Fixed. Anyway, there is no such thing as an app-display in the macOS windowing model. If you run all your apps on the leftmost display, drag the menu bar to your leftmost display.
